# How to exit from MC SSH panel

Tags: sftp, mc

For example I make SFTP link in my left panel.
How can I revert this panel back to my machine, so that I have listing of my local files?

One way I found is to enable "command prompt" in MC layout (which I prefer disabled) and then run `cd`.
Hoping for another way...

Comment: Have you tried `Alt-Y`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

press enter on the `..` when you're in the root of sshfs.

Comment: hm, that just brings me to root of shhfs but without `..` on top of file listing

Comment: however I found that I can just use directory history option, thou not sure if that resets connection...

Comment: then upgrade your mc. mine is version 4.8.17 .

Comment: same here, Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: ah, you are right, sorry...